# CSS Visibility property not working in Firefox, inner <a> tag not displaying when hover div

Tags: css, visibility

CSS Visibility property is working perfectly in Chrome but not in IE and Firefox.what to do?.

```
I tried both display:none and display:block
```

as well as `visibility:hidden and visibility:visible`
In chrome both cases are working perfectly but not in IE and Firefox.

Any input would be really appreciated thanks :)

Please see this JSFiddle: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/5dhmp6qf/)

Issue is Solved.

For anyone facing this type of issues take a look at the updated JSfiddle[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/5dhmp6qf/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this: *Note:* This is a way to solve your problem

```css
.circle {
  margin: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #1d2087;
}

.circle::before,
.circle::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
.circle,
.circle::before,
.circle::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #5c5eae;
  color: transparent;
  line-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle::after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
  transform: scale(.5);
}
.circle:hover::after {
  background: #5c5eae;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
  transform: scale(.9);
}

.circle1 {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.circle2 {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.circle3 {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.circle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: transparent;
}

.circle h2 {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.circle h2 small {
  color: transparent;
}

.circle p {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
a.hyper:hover {
 color: #fff;
  visibility: visible;
}

a:hover, p:hover, .circle:hover, h2:hover{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="font-family: arial;">
        <div class="circle" id="userImg" style="background-image: url('http://i68.tinypic.com/1zfr32v.png'); background-position: center;">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="LoadUrl('upd-details.jsp',1)" class="hyper"><h1>Profile<small></small><p>Update</p></h1></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Note:** You can also remove `visibility` property if you want to, since it is not needed in your code.